# XCUITest and dynamically generated views

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

For XCUITest related work, how can I access classes of my app?

I have a set of screens that are dynamically generated (in this case, onboarding questions I ask the user across multiple view controllers) off a JSON structure I control server-side. I won't know what content the JSON API will produce, such that I could just write declarative UI testing code inside a XCUITest.

I'd like to be able to access with my XCUITest a set of wrapper classes around the JSON structure to fetch out relevant bits of information that clue me into the content on those screens so I can emulate filling them in correctly. With some basic Google'ing it's clear XCUITests sit outside the main target/app's code but I haven’t found any strategies to get access to it within a XCUITest.

If there is no direct way to do this (is there?), what are some good alternatives?

At this point, I'm thinking of embedding a hidden view object within my VCs' hierarchy that I can invoke with an XCUITest to actually fill in the content (since I have visibility to my JSON-managing classes).

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be ok to write a regular unit-test that compares the view with a static image?

Comment: There is no way to access classes of the app. I use a special view which is present in hierarchy only in debug mode.

Comment: You can integrate GCDWebserver in your app. This way your test app can behave as a client and your main app can behave as a server. Since the main app has access to all classes, it can send the response data to your test app with this mechanism. Link the library: https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, XCUITests are compiled and executed separately from your app. There's no way for your tests to access any code from your app. XCUITests work off of the accessibility tree for your app's UI.

The idea behind XCUITests is to keep the tests as close to the end users' flow as possible. I'd structure your tests around checking for the unique content types and combinations you could expect to load. But if you must have some extra clues to help your tests run, I'd recommend having a separate Scheme in your Xcode project that runs your tests against a Debug build configuration that either pre-populates your app with an example dataset you can run your tests against. Or include some extra UI elements in the scheme detailing specifics about the UI that loads at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Internal custom extensions over classes can expose functions & attributes you'd like to access.